# How to Quiesce a particular domain in datapower?

Tags: ibm-datapower

I need to quiesce all the multi protocol gateway components in a particular domain ( not default ) in datapower appliance. I could see quiesce option only in each multi protocol gateway level. is there an option in domain level to quiesce all MPGW?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can quiesce a whole domain or object by object.
The only other option is to create a SOMA or REST script to quiesce each object (=MPGW) by name.

Answer (score 0):

As said either you can quiesce an application domain or a particular object. If you are familiar with Java and Soma templates, you can keep the list of MPGW name in a property file and iterate through and execute the Soma command for each MPGW.

Let me know if this helps.